# Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (23.1.0) and test app (23.0.1) differ

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-espresso

When building I get the following error:

```
Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (23.1.0) and test app (23.0.1) differ.
```

These are my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'com.snappydb:snappydb-lib:0.5.2'
    compile 'com.esotericsoftware.kryo:kryo:2.24.0'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.0.1'
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.0.1'
    compile 'javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.0.1'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.14'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.10.19'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.1'
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.3.1'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.3.1'
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I can tell you that the 23.1.0 dependency comes from the appcompat lib, because that includes the annotations lib. The 23.0.1 I don't know

Comment: It doesn't work either if I switch appcompat back to 23.0.1

Comment: I just Replaced 23.1.0 by 23.0.1, everywhere in dependency, worked for me.

Comment: Add annotation dependency related to your version error. https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/errorexecution-failed-for-task-apppredebugandroidtestbuild-conflict-with-dependency-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-android/

Comment: Or might this help you https://readyandroid.wordpress.com/conflict-with-dependency-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-resolved-versions-for-app-23-1-0-and-test-app-23-0-1-differ/

Answer (score 208, accepted):

You can force the annotation library in your test using:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
```

Something like this:

```
  // Force usage of support annotations in the test app, since it is internally used by the runner module.
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.1'
  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-web:2.2.1'
```

Another solution is to use this in the top level file:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'
}
```

Comment: This line was the solution:androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0'

Comment: The use of the configurations.all setting worked for me, but not in the project level file, which is what I interpreted initially as "top level file" from the response above.  It was in the module level build.gradle file

Comment: Is this conflict caused by Espresso originally?

Comment: resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.4.0' doesn't help for me.. problem is EspressoContribution for DatePicker, DrawerActions, RecyclerView, etc.. ('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2'){
            exclude module: 'support-annotations'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
}

Comment: Just one important point, to make it clear that We need to add configurations.all { resolutionStrategy.force 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0' } inside `build.gradle` of the **module(app)** to fix the issue.

Comment: I just added this line " androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.0' " to build.gradle and error was disappeared, Thanks.

Comment: Yeah,It solved my problem but after adding that line,I had done clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: I had to remove this one also. androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.2') {

Answer (score 69):

Project Rebuild solved my problem.

In Android studio in the toolbar..
Build>Rebuild Project.

Answer (score 25):

Source: [CodePath - UI Testing With Espresso](https://guides.codepath.com/android/UI-Testing-with-Espresso#android-studio-setup)

> 6. Finally, we need to pull in the Espresso dependencies and set the test runner in our app build.gradle:

```
// build.gradle
...
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

dependencies {
    ...
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2') {
        // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since Espresso
        // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test:runner:0.5') {
        // Necessary if your app targets Marshmallow (since the test runner
        // hasn't moved to Marshmallow yet)
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }
}
```

I've added that to my gradle file and the warning disappeared.

Also, if you get any other dependency listed as conflicting, such as support-annotations, try excluding it too from the androidTestCompile dependencies.

Comment: excluding the individual androidtestcompile works for me

Answer (score 13):

you can try to use

```
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

instead of

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.4.1'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:rules:0.4.1'

androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.1'
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-contrib:2.2.1'
```

Answer (score 6):

I was getting this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for details.

I was having following dependencies in my *build.gradle* file under *Gradle Scripts*

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

So, I resolved it by commenting the following dependencies

```
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
```

So my dependencies look like this

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
//testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
//androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: So you removed the testing libraries? This isn't very helpful if you need those libraries.

Answer (score 4):

**I was getting the same error today:**

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.>
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in
>   project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app
>   (27.1.1) differ.

**What I did:**

- I simply updated all my dependencies to `27.1.1` instead of `26.1.0`
- Also, updated my `compileSdkVersion 27` and `targetSdkVersion 27` which were `26` earlier

And `com.android.support:support-annotations` error was gone!

**For Ref:**

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added below code in dependencies of app level build.gradle

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

After that, I clean the project and rebuild.My problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Chang your application level build.gradle file's:

`implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'`

to

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.yourpackagename"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```