# Android. How to use Espresso 2.2.2 with support library 24.1.1?

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-espresso

This is my test:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
@MediumTest
public class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mainActivityActivityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<MainActivity>(MainActivity.class);

    @Test
    public void buttonShouldBePresent(){
        Intents.init();
        onView(withId(R.id.button)).perform(click());
        intended(hasComponent(SecondActivity.class.getName()));
    }


}
```

I have these dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:preference-v7:24.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'

}
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error:Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations'. Resolved versions for app (24.1.1) and test app (23.1.1) differ. See http://g.co/androidstudio/app-test-app-conflict for details.
```

Tried to use support library with earlier version (could import successfully but cannot use TextInputEditText):

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'

    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-intents:2.2.2'
    androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force('com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1')
    }
}
```

I could import earlier version, but 2 reasons which makes me unable to use earlier version.

1. I am using TextInputEditText which is not available in earlier version
2. Project requirement

   - Android Studio 2.1+
   - Android SDK Platform-tools 24+
   - Android SDK Tools 25+
   - SDK Build Tools 24.0.0
   - Android Support Repository 34+
   - Android SDK Platform 24

How can I solve this problem without lowering support library version?

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317555/conflict-with-dependency-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-resolved-ver/33318482#33318482

Answer (score 2):

You can force the annotation library in your test using:

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Exclude `support-annotations` from Espresso.

```
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
```

You can't mix support library versions (e.g. 24.x.x everything with 23.1.1 `support-annotations` so remove this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force('com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1')
}
```

Pro tip:

`design` depends on `appcompat-v7` and `recyclerview-v7` so you don't need to specify them.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions to fix it:

- The easiest way would be to **include** in your dependencies this line:

  androidTestCompile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:24.1.1'

and remove this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force('com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1')
}
```

- Another way would be **exclude** `android:support:annotations` libs:

  ```
  androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
      module: 'support-annotations'
  })
  ```

and remove this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy.force('com.android.support:support-annotations:23.1.1')
}
```

`Espresso` and its all artifacts like `web` or `intents` are using Android Support libraries in version `23.1.1`and older (`espresso-contrib`)

Notice that the latest version of Android Support Library is already `24.2.0`, not `24.1.1`.

Hope it will help