# Issue related to Android studio installation

Tags: android-studio

I am facing this error when installing Android Studio:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'.
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app (27.1.1) differ

Comment: Add `build.gradle`. Or follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317555/conflict-with-dependency-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-resolved-ver.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android support library error after updating to 23.3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36833606/android-support-library-error-after-updating-to-23-3-0)