# Error when opening Android Studio 3.0.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Whenever I open my Android Studio 3.0.1 , I got this error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild'. >
>   Conflict with dependency 'com.android.support:support-annotations' in
>   project ':app'. Resolved versions for app (26.1.0) and test app
>   (27.1.1) differ. See
>   https://d.android.com/r/tools/test-apk-dependency-conflicts.html for
>   details.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33317555/conflict-with-dependency-com-android-supportsupport-annotations-resolved-ver

Answer (score 0):

use same version of dependencies
com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same problem.So I am sharing solution which worked for me.Hope, help for you as well.

Go to the module level build.gradle in android studio and then change these three value that given below , sync the gradle.Install the plugin whatever android studio asking for downloading.

1. compileSdkVersion 27
2. targetSdkVersion 27
3. implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'